# lg v20 locked by frp

Tags: lg, locked-out

I have an lg v20 android version 8 that's frp locked. It's been unused for a couple of years now and I decided to charge the battery and give it a go. It doesn't even have an sd card from at&t. I turned it on and I was greeted with the  regular screen when you start the phone as new. So I went a couole of screens later, i even connected to my WiFi at home and then I'm hit with the message that I need to get into the gmail account and password etc. if I hit forgot password apparently google sends a message to that gmail account.
I have tried holding the volume diwn bottom with on and of button etc and no dice. The person at at&t did the same thing snd nothing. Can anyone please help me? TIA
Chileno